# Timestamp format is not supporting the React `react-datepicker` as default value

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

My date-time format from the api result is `2019-12-30T06:16:48.453Z`. It is not supported by the `react-datepicker`.

My code is following and is a functional component. I didn't write the complete code below. Added just the required parts.

```
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

<DatePicker
    selected={'2019-12-30T06:16:48.453Z'}
    {...props}
/>
```

I also tried adding `moment` by importing it and used as `selected={moment('2019-12-30T06:16:48.453Z')}`

I'm getting the error in both cases like `Maximum update depth exceeded`.

Comment: when you give selected={moment('2019-12-30')} is it working ? without time

Comment: No, the same error.

Comment: This error - Maximum update depth exceeded - is about infinite loop in your react app. You have somewhere logic that is updating compontent, and updated component is triggering new update and so on, and so on. You should first try to solve that

Comment: I'm using `Formik` library similar to Redux-Form and no more updations in my own ways.

Comment: @Hareesh the selected prop accepts an object not a string, so you need to convert it using native Date. Added the answer kindly check and let me know if you need any further clarifications on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still version 1.8 of react datepicker they were using moment, to reduce the package size they are using the native Date Objects. [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53501134/react-datepicker-momentjs-invalid-date)

So you can update your code as shown below

```
 function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DatePicker selected={new Date("2019-12-30")} />
      <DatePicker selected={new Date("2019-12-30T06:16:48.453Z")} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/59529781-so-3etmz)

**Update**

to get the required format react datepicker has a prop called       dateFormat,  so you can add like this `dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"`, See [here](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/blob/master/docs/datepicker.md)

Comment: This one works but the format is not working `dateFormat={'dd-MM-yyyy}` and it shows the default format. This is working when the date changes by selecting from the datepicker.

Comment: @Hareesh basically  you need to transform it your required format in native Date, i think that will work, as mentioned in the question added the answer in that format so basically you want to show it in dd-mm-yyyy format, am i correct

Answer (score 0):

> Maximum update depth exceeded

This error happens when your function call inside return of render method exceeds limits. Can you checkout any other function calls inside your component.

And for

> react-datepicker

try basic JavaScript Date api.

```
selected={new Date('2019-12-30T06:16:48.453Z')}
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

```js
 const datee='2019-12-30T06:16:48.453Z';
 let filt = Date(datee);
 console.log(filt);
 document.write(filt);
```

Answer (score 0):

This error about infinite loop .
You can check this issue : [ReactJS: Maximum update depth exceeded error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497358/reactjs-maximum-update-depth-exceeded-error) 
And also you can set dateFormat in DatePicker component like : dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy h:mm aa"
Check this for formats: https://reactdatepicker.com/